Nested routers do not work when deploying a React app on Vercel
I'm having an issue with react-router when deploying the react app via Vercel. It can't navigate to nested routes even though it works fine locally
//App.jsx
<BrowserRouter>
      <Header></Header>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='' element={<Home />}></Route>
        <Route path='product/:slug' element={<Product />}></Route>
        <Route path="issue/:slug" element={<Issue />}></Route>
        <Route path="category/:slug" element={<Category />}></Route>
        <Route path="login" element={<LoginAdmin />}></Route>
        <Route path="dashboard" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path="product">
            <Route index element={<Navigate to="list" />}></Route>
            <Route path="create" element={<CreateProduct apiLink={apiLink} />}></Route>
            <Route path="list" element={<ListProduct />}></Route>
            <Route path="edit/:ID" element={<EditProduct apiLink={apiLink} />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="category">
            <Route index element={<Navigate to="list" />}></Route>
            <Route path="list" element={<ListCategory />}></Route>
            <Route path="create" element={<CreateSubCategory apiLink={apiLink} />}></Route>
            <Route path="edit/:ID" element={<EditCategory apiLink={apiLink} />}></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="issue">
            <Route index element={<Navigate to="list" />}></Route>
            <Route path="create" element={<CreateIssue apiLink={apiLink} />}></Route>
            <Route path="list" element={<ListIssue />}></Route>
            <Route path="edit/:ID" element={<EditIssue apiLink={apiLink} />}></Route>
          </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />}></Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer></Footer>
      <ContactSocial></ContactSocial>
    </BrowserRouter>

I've also added the vercel.json file, but I still can't access those routes
vercel.json
{
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/"
        }
    ]
}

I want to be able to access those routes after deploying them on Vercel.

Do you mean you can't navigate internally to these routes via Link or navigate, or are you trying to navigate directly to them via the browser's address bar? See if the Vercel deployment docs are helpful. If not can you [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] and where/how you are deploying the app and what your exact reproduction steps are?

Having the same issue. Top level routes works fine but the nested ones don't. I also added the vercel.json and using react 18.3.1 + vite 5.3.5 + react-router-dom 6.25.1

same issue here and couldnt find any fix yet.

It took my two days to investigate, but finally it is resolved by upgrading the rollup package to the latest version:
npm upgrade rollup
// OR
pnpm upgrade rollup
// OR
yarn upgrade rollup

Source: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/11480#issuecomment-2070780285

Having a similar issue with nested routes. Everything works locally, and I have the same vercel JSON. All routes should render using  as a parent. The /places route works. But all of the nested routes do not.
It all works in local dev.
Example routes:
<ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
  <Box style={styleLayout} className="sff">
    <ConfirmProvider>
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/places/:id/:place" element={<Map />} /> // THIS ROUTE WORKS (CAUSES A DIALOG TO DISPLAY)
          <Route path="/" element={<Map />}> // NO ROUTES BELOW THIS RENDER
            <Route path="signin" element={<Signin />} />
            <Route path="events/:eventID/:eventTitle" element={<EventDetails />} />
            <Route path="events" element={<Events />} />
            <Route path="pages/:pageSlug" element={<Pages />} />
            <Route path="pages" element={<Pages />} />
            <Route path="admin" element={<AdminLayout />}>
              <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path=':type/' element={<ListContent />} />
              <Route path='locations/add' element={<AdminLocations />} />
              <Route path='locations/update/:updateId' element={<AdminLocations />} />
              <Route path='events/add' element={<AdminEvents />} />
              <Route path='events/update/:updateId' element={<AdminEvents />} />
              <Route path='pages/add' element={<AdminPages />} />
              <Route path='pages/update/:updateId' element={<AdminPages />} />
              <Route path='settings/' element={<AdminSettings />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </ConfirmProvider>
  </Box>
  <Analytics />
</ThemeProvider>

